# Building a real-time data pipeline for weather prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, apache-kafka, bigdata

I have been given an mini-project to get done as a starter in the big data world and I would love to know what methodology or what tools to use in order to build a real-time data pipeline.

Below is the assignment:

> « As a Chicago citizen I would like to know what will be the weather
>   for the next 24 hour with a prediction at each 15 minutes. We want to
>   evaluate how you create a data pipeline, with a monitoring and fault
>   tolerance, you can plug the pipeline to a basic Machine learning
>   Algorithm. You could find historical dataset on
>   http://www.ogimet.com/metars.phtml.en and live stream at
>   https://www.aviationweather.gov/dataserver all other relevant data set
>   are welcome. »

I tried to solve this challenge using just simple Python for data exraction and transformation on a Google Colab notebook but I'm not having the feeling that this is the right methodoloy, neither the good tools, to use!

Here is what I first tried to extract historical weather data:

```
years = ['2018', '2017', '2016']
format_ ="txt"
months = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12']
start_day = '01'
end_day = '30'
for year in years:
  for month in months:
    query_url = "http://www.ogimet.com/display_metars2.php?lang=en&lugar=WSAP&tipo=SA&ord=REV&nil=SI&fmt={4}&ano={0}&mes={1}&day={2}&hora=00&anof={0}&mesf={1}&dayf={3}&horaf=00&minf=59&send=send".format(year, month, start_day, end_day, format_ )
    requests.get(query_url)
    filename = "chicago{0}{1}".format(year, month)
    r = requests.get(query_url)
    end = r.text.find('</pre>')
    with open(filename, 'w') as file: 
      file.write(r.text[1670:end])
    print(r.text)
```

This sometimes returns a rate limit for requests, so I tried using the World Weather Online API that helped me get historical data in a csv file:

```
from wwo_hist import retrieve_hist_data

# export_csv: bool, default = True
# If False, no csv file will be exported to current directory.
# store_df: bool, default = False
# If True, retrieved dataframe(s) will be stored as list in the work space.

def get_hist_data(api_key,location,start_date,end_date,frequency):
  """
    api_key: string
  (Premium/ free trial) API key from worldweatheronline.com

  location_list: list of string
  US Zipcode, UK Postcode, Canada Postalcode, IP address, Latitude/Longitude (decimal degree) or city name

  start_date: string
  Preferred date format: 'dd-mmm-yyyy'

  end_date: string
  Preferred date format: 'dd-mmm-yyyy'

  frequency: integer
  1, 3, 6, 12, 24
  1 hourly, 3 hourly, 6 hourly, 12 hourly (day/night) or 24 hourly (day average)

  location_label: bool, default = False
  If True, all column names will have city name as prefix.

  export_csv: bool, default = True
  If False, no csv file will be exported to current directory.

  store_df: bool, default = False
  If True, retrieved dataframe(s) will be stored as list in the work space.

  """
  hist_weather_data = retrieve_hist_data(api_key,
                                location,
                                start_date,
                                end_date,
                                frequency,
                                location_label = False,
                                export_csv = True,
                                store_df = True)
  return "Done"
```

My question is: How can I approach this challenge/problem? What is the methdology to follow or the tools to use ? Is it possible to get it done using just Python and runing the final script on a virtual machine every day to get these predictions in the end?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Although your question is very broad/open ended, I will answer it to the best of my ability. Since you're asking about a methodology, I will not worry about the code you posted about how you processed the data, but rather what it can be run through.

> "As a Chicago citizen I would like to know what will be the weather for the next 24 hour with a prediction at each 15 minutes."

This to me sounds like a problem that you wish to view previous/historical data and immediately adjust your model based off what you just saw.  This is perfect for a RNN (recurrent neural network). An RNN looks processes new data it has just received and adjusts the model with higher importance on the more recent data. These are typically used in time series data, such as stock market predictions (your data is time series data as well, so it should be a perfect solution).

If you wish to try another approach, you could do it through a probabilistic approach such as Naive Bayes.  An example of Naive Bayes is as follows: You are told it is windy and cloudy, then based off previous data from similar events, you determine there is a 60% chance of rain, 20% chance of snow, 10% chance of sleet/hail, and 10% chance of sun. This is probably not as useful for your problem as it requires a ton of per-processing of the data, and done very specifically. For each row (some date/time), you would have to have a column for each type of weather, then go through and label them using binary, 1 if the type of weather occurred, 0 if it didn't.

Lastly, you could try a basic NN (neural network), but my recommendation would be to just use an RNN instead.

Overall, your best bet since it is time-series data is to use an RNN.  All of that code can be written in python using the keras library (it include examples/example data sets so you can see how it works). And yes, I would recommending using a virtual machine to run your code, as running an RNN can take forever on large data sets.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort and your time. Yes, your answer was very helpful. However, it is the first part of the project that I bleive is most important. It's the data acquisition part and setting an almost real-time data pipeline that feeds data in our model.

Comment: I agree.  Often times implementing a AI/ML method can be one of the easiest parts. Data processing is the part that is incredibly time consuming and essential, since there is no way to perform any operation on that data if it is not formatted properly, orderly, etc.